# Excel - day/date/time to determine peak/offpeak

Tags: excel, date, time

I'm trying to determine from a .csv file output (below) if the date/time meets our criteria for peak or off-peak.  Peak/off-peak is determined by the day of the week and time. I'm trying to build a formula in excel that lets me know if each date/time is peak or off-peak.  I have been using the text to column feature to put the data into two cells then use the TEXT function to determine day of the week in a new cell, then filter feature to input peak/off-peak.  This is very manual and inefficient.  Thanks in advance.

Peak equals:

```
- mon, tue, wed thurs, fri and hour 6:00-21:00
```

Off-peak equals:

```
- sat, sun and hour 0:00-23:00 
- mon, tue, wed thurs, fri and hour 0:00-5:00 and 22:00-23:00
```

File output:

```
8/15/2017 0:00
8/15/2017 1:00
8/15/2017 2:00
8/15/2017 3:00
```

Seeking Outcome:

```
Date/Time       peak/off-peak
8/15/2017 0:00  off-peak
8/15/2017 1:00  off-peak
8/15/2017 2:00  off-peak
8/15/2017 3:00  off-peak
8/15/2017 4:00  off-peak
8/15/2017 5:00  off-peak
8/15/2017 6:00  peak
8/15/2017 7:00  peak
8/15/2017 8:00  peak
8/15/2017 9:00  peak
8/15/2017 10:00 peak
8/15/2017 11:00 peak
8/15/2017 12:00 peak
8/15/2017 13:00 peak
8/15/2017 14:00 peak
8/15/2017 15:00 peak
8/15/2017 16:00 peak
8/15/2017 17:00 peak
8/15/2017 18:00 peak
8/15/2017 19:00 peak
8/15/2017 20:00 peak
8/15/2017 21:00 peak
8/15/2017 22:00 off-peak
8/15/2017 23:00 off-peak
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the following formula in the B1 cell, where A1 is the cell containing the Date/Time:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A1,2)<=5,WEEKDAY(A1,2)>=1,A1-INT(A1)>=0.25,A1-INT(A1)<=0.875),"peak","off-peak")
```

The part `WEEKDAY(A1,2)<=5,WEEKDAY(A1,2)>=1` checks if the day is between Mon and Fri and the part `A1-INT(A1)>=0.25,A1-INT(A1)<=0.875` checks if the hour is between 06:00 and 21:00. If every conditions are TRUE, the formula shows "**peak**" otherwise it shows "**off-peak**".