# Excel - time of year/day/date/time to determine peak/offpeak

Tags: excel, date

I'm looking for a formula in excel that lets me know if a date each date/time is peak or off-peak (electricity use data). Peak/off-peak is determined by the season, day of the week and time.

Peak equals:

```
JUNE-SEPTEMBER (SUMMER)
- mon, tue, wed thurs, fri and hour 9:00-18:00
OCTOBER-MAY (WINTER)
-mon, tue, wed, thurs, fri and hours 8:00-21:00
```

Off-peak - All other hours. (ie where this is false)

I have the code to determine if something is off/on peak individually:

June-September

```
IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2,2)<=5,WEEKDAY(A2,2)>=1,A2-INT(A2)>=0.375,A2-INT(A2)<=0.75),"peak","off-peak"))
```

October-May

```
IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2,2)<=5,WEEKDAY(A2,2)>=1,A2-INT(A2)>=0.333,A2-INT(A2)<=0.875),"peak","off-peak"))
```

However, my problem is I don't know how to put these together with a date like 
01/02/2019 09:00 to do the first step to determine if it qualifies as SUMMER or WINTER. Would this be workable with a nested `IF` in excel? I can't seem to get this.

Making a separate column with an `If` statement that shows if the date is winter or summer is easy, and I've done it. But I still don't know how to combine this with the above functions.

Many thanks.

[Excel - day/date/time to determine peak/offpeak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346612/excel-day-date-time-to-determine-peak-offpeak/55622352#55622352)

I want the output to just tell me peak or off peak, but the variable hours depending on the time of year is tripping me up.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah nested if statements. If you've got your formula for SUMMER/WINTER in A1, then nest like this:

`=IF($A$1="SUMMER",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2,2)<=5,WEEKDAY(A2,2)>=1,A2-INT(A2)>=0.375,A2-INT(A2)<=0.75),"peak","off-peak")),IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2,2)<=5,WEEKDAY(A2,2)>=1,A2-INT(A2)>=0.333,A2-INT(A2)<=0.875),"peak","off-peak")))`

Answer (score 0):

The WEEKDAY function is really MOD(*<date>*, 7) with some adjustments. Using MOD, anything less than 2 is Saturday or Sunday.

The HOUR function quickly converts true time to an integer that can be compared to a set of paramters which are adjusted for summer/winter.

```
=IF(OR(MOD(A2, 7)<2, HOUR(A2)<(9-ISNA(MATCH(MONTH(A2), {6,7,8,9}, 0))), HOUR(A2)>(18+ISNA(MATCH(MONTH(A2), {6,7,8,9}, 0))*3)), "off-", "")&"peak"
```